# Presto: Cannot INSERT values

Tags: hadoop, presto

I can create and drop tables and do query normally in Presto, but when I use `insert`, it's always wrong as shown bellow:

```
presto:default> create table test.lll (a int);
CREATE TABLE
presto:default> insert into test.lll select 1;

Query 20180104_091933_00007_k8e78, FAILED, 5 nodes
Splits: 84 total, 30 done (35.71%)
0:00 [0 rows, 0B] [0 rows/s, 0B/s]

Query 20180104_091933_00007_k8e78 failed: No page sink provider for connector 'hive'
```

What is the reason and how to address it? Any help is appreciated.

---

`Error Type`:   `INTERNAL_ERROR`

`Error Code`:   `GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR (65536)`

Full stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No page sink provider for connector 'hive'
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:191)
    at com.facebook.presto.split.PageSinkManager.providerFor(PageSinkManager.java:67)
    at com.facebook.presto.split.PageSinkManager.createPageSink(PageSinkManager.java:61)
    at com.facebook.presto.operator.TableWriterOperator$TableWriterOperatorFactory.createPageSink(TableWriterOperator.java:97)
    at com.facebook.presto.operator.TableWriterOperator$TableWriterOperatorFactory.createOperator(TableWriterOperator.java:88)
    at com.facebook.presto.operator.DriverFactory.createDriver(DriverFactory.java:92)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlTaskExecution$DriverSplitRunnerFactory.createDriver(SqlTaskExecution.java:515)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlTaskExecution$DriverSplitRunnerFactory.access$1400(SqlTaskExecution.java:490)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlTaskExecution$DriverSplitRunner.processFor(SqlTaskExecution.java:616)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.executor.PrioritizedSplitRunner.process(PrioritizedSplitRunner.java:163)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.executor.LegacyPrioritizedSplitRunner.process(LegacyPrioritizedSplitRunner.java:23)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.executor.TaskExecutor$TaskRunner.run(TaskExecutor.java:492)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`
```

Comment: What presto version are you using? What connector the 'hive' catalog actually uses?

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen Hi Piotr, my presto version is 0.189 and the connector is 'hive-hadoop2'

Comment: Can you post whole stack trace? You should be able see from web interface. See https://prestodb.io/docs/current/admin/web-interface.html

Comment: @kokosing Thx for your reply man. I just updated the stack trace.

Comment: Are you sure you have `hive.properties` with the same content propagated to all the presto nodes?

Comment: @SuperDelta Did you solved your issue?